# populate combobox from an excel sheet based on listbox selection (multiselect enabled)

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, listbox, multi-select

I have a listbox with 3 values and multi select option enabled. Based on the values selected, I want to populate a combobox by referring to certain ranges in excel sheet. The code below works if only one value is selected from listbox. I know it will not work for multiple selections, but I am unable to write code to loop through the list of selections and then add corresponding ranges to combo box.

So, if I select customer1 and customer2, i want the values in ranges d3:d34 AND c4:c24 populated in the combobox. similarly for other combinations too. However, if one of the values is unselected, corresponding values should be cleared from the combobox.

If I were to save all the selected items in listbox in an array, how do i do a "search" or "find" for each of the values stored in the array?

Please suggest how I could revise this code.

Thank you!

```
Private Sub Combobox1_DropButtonClick()

    Dim curSelected As String
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To Listbox1.ListCount - 1
        If Listbox1.Selected(i) Then
            curSelected = Listbox1.List(i)
                If curSelected = "customer1" Then
                    ChooseDeals.List = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("d4:d34").Value
                ElseIf curSelected = "customer2" Then
                    ChooseDeals.List = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("c4:c24").Value
                ElseIf curSelected = "customer3" Then
                    ChooseDeals.List = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("e4:e20").Value
                End If
          End If
    Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to set a `ComboBox.List` to a discontiguous `Range`, so I think you're forced to add the values one cell at a time.

This code takes advantage of the [Range.Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174786%28v=office.11%29.aspx) property, and the fact that the Areas are defined discretely in the order they appear in the assignment.

For example if you type this in the Debug window:

```
? Activesheet.Range("B1,A1").Areas.Count
```

you get 2, even though it's a contiguous range that would yield only one `Area` if you defined it as:

```
? Activesheet.Range("A1:B1").Areas.Count
```

Further, if you alter the first one to:

```
? Activesheet.Range("B1,A1").Areas(1).Address
```

you'll get "B1" even though "A1" appears before it in the spreadsheet.

So, I thought you could use this to "line up" your `ListBox` items and their selected `Ranges`:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim FullRange As Excel.Range
Dim RangeToUse As Excel.Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim AreaToUse

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set FullRange = ws.Range("d4:d34,c4:c24,e4:e20")
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        If RangeToUse Is Nothing Then
            Set RangeToUse = FullRange.Areas(i + 1)
        Else
            Set RangeToUse = Union(RangeToUse, FullRange.Areas(i + 1))
        End If
    End If
Next i
If Not RangeToUse Is Nothing Then
    For Each AreaToUse In RangeToUse
        For Each cell In AreaToUse
            ComboBox1.AddItem cell.Value
        Next cell
    Next AreaToUse
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing recently. I called a validation sub on selecting the cell in which the combobox is placed. The validation program would dynamically check how many values are there in a list that is maintained separately and populate the data validation list for the cell accordingly. A separate sub will list may have to be created which updates the list. and this sub may be called before populating the data validation list. The following code worked for me. You may have to use a variant.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D7")) Is Nothing Then

    Call getValidation

End If
End Sub

Sub getValidation()

Dim j As Integer
j = 0

   j = Range("Charts!XFA1").Offset(Sheet1.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row

' data list stored in Charts!XFA column. Found last row where the list ends.

If j > 1 Then

Range("QueryingTool!D7").Select  'D7 is the cell where data validation is used
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=Charts!$XFA7:$XFA" & j
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End If

End Sub
```